# creating variables and naming them dynamically javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, dynamic

so imagine I have an array like this:

```
var array = ['Apple','Orange','Banana','Melon'];
```

And I want to create variables just by looking at that array, like following:

```
var apple;
var orange;
var banana;
var melon;
```

How can I achieve this without using objects?

Comment: Locally scoped to a function, or globally scoped?

Comment: The only place you can do this is by adding them as global variables (bleuch) that are also accessible as properties of the `window` object.  Use another object, instead.

Comment: I have intention to create global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do this:

```
    var array = ['Apple','Orange','Banana','Melon'];
    for(var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) 
        this[array[i].toLowerCase()] = 'something...';
```

If you are in general scope `this` is `window` otherwise it is the local context

Comment: Thanks so much, using this[variableName] = variableName solved my problem!

Comment: You are so welcome. Happy to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the global scope you could create the variables using `window` object

```
var array = ['Apple','Orange','Banana','Melon'];

array.forEach(e => window[e.toLowerCase()] = e);

console.log(apple); // Apple
```